# Create “Application for a Site” in Sitecore 10.2 containers

Tags: iis, container

We are migrating our existing solution from Sitecore 8.2 (IaaS) to Sitecore 10.2 containers. Migration is completed for the main site, but one of our main functionality is hosted as  [“Application for a Site”](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/) configuration under our main IIS site and uses a dedicated Application pool. Now we would like to implement the same in containers. We couldn’t find enough documentation for the same. Could you please help us with the steps? Attached is a screenshot for reference.
[image: Site Node in IIS]

Comment: Just create a container for your application. It's a regular IIS application, there are plenty of documentation for it on the web. E.g. https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/11/20/iis-on-windows-server-containers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just create a image of your application and deploy it on docker on your local machine and the you can try with other non production environments.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you can create this in a separate container but if you want to recreate same setup then you will have to run `appcmd` from your `dockerfile` to replicate the existing application for a site setup. Appcmd is well documented for example [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe). To run this from your `dockerfile` you would do something like:

```
RUN <win path>\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add app /site.name:MySite /path:/app1 /physicalPath:C:\inetpub\mysite\app1
```